# Web API Required Facebook Permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api

I have an app that requires both email and user_friends permissions from facebook when they log in. I want to make these permissions required, like the public_profile permission is by default. Is it possible to do this? At the moment if they edit the permissions and remove them, my app does not work and I am not sure how to handle this scenario (where to do it?).

My Startup.Auth.cs file looks like this;

```
    var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AppId = "**",
        AppSecret = "**",
        Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Facebook"));
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:email", context.Email, ClaimValueTypes.Email, "Facebook"));
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        },
    };
    facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
    facebookOptions.Scope.Add("user_friends");
    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
}
```

The two lines I want to make 'required' are;

```
    facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
    facebookOptions.Scope.Add("user_friends");
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Or any direction on how to handle the case of the user removing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

What you can do is if the user don't give you the permissions you tell the user why you need them and give them a button to click if they want to give it to you.

You should also be aware that not all Facebook users have an email address.